# Convert data to an object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I have a FlutterFlow project that has a custom widget. The widget is getting data as a parameter from an external datasource, the data is then passed to a [graphic](https://pub.dev/packages/graphic) chart

The data from the API (Parameter) looks like this:

`[{name: John Doe, value: 12}, {name: Jane Doe, value: 14}]`

This is the correct data, however, the quatations marks are missing, and for me to use the data it needs to be:

`[{"name": "John Doe", "value": 12}, {"name": "Jane Doe", "value": 14}]`

How do I convert this data to the correct format mentioned above, and use it the chart (line:    `data: chartData ?? defaultData`)

Here is the full Custom Widget code block:

```
class TransposedChartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TransposedChartPage({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.chartTitle,
    this.chartData,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String? chartTitle;
  final dynamic chartData;

  @override
  _TransposedChartPageState createState() => _TransposedChartPageState();
}


const defaultData = [
  {"name": "No Data", "value": 0},
];

class _TransposedChartPageState extends State<TransposedChartPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 20, 5),
                child: Text(
                  widget.chartTitle ?? "",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                width: widget.width ?? 350,
                height: 300,
                child: Chart(
                  data: chartData ?? defaultData,
                  variables: {
                    'name': Variable(
                      accessor: (Map map) => map['name'] as String,
                    ),
                    'value': Variable(
                      accessor: (Map map) => map['value'] as num,
                    ),
                  },
                  marks: [
                    IntervalMark(
                      label: LabelEncode(
                          encoder: (tuple) => Label(tuple['value'].toString())),
                      gradient: GradientEncode(
                          value: const LinearGradient(colors: [
                            Color(0x8883bff6),
                            Color(0x88188df0),
                            Color(0xcc188df0),
                          ], stops: [
                            0,
                            0.5,
                            1
                          ]),
                          updaters: {
                            'tap': {
                              true: (_) => const LinearGradient(colors: [
                                    Color(0xee83bff6),
                                    Color(0xee3f78f7),
                                    Color(0xff3f78f7),
                                  ], stops: [
                                    0,
                                    0.7,
                                    1
                                  ])
                            }
                          }),
                    )
                  ],
                  coord: RectCoord(transposed: true),
                  axes: [
                    Defaults.verticalAxis
                      ..line = Defaults.strokeStyle
                      ..grid = null,
                    Defaults.horizontalAxis
                      ..line = null
                      ..grid = Defaults.strokeStyle,
                  ],
                  selections: {'tap': PointSelection(dim: Dim.x)},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using `jsonEncode` which seems to to do the conversion when I log it, however, when I convert this data on the chart (`data: jsonEncode(widget.chartData`) ?? defaultData,) , it seems to break.

FYI: I am new to dart/flutter, so I might have missed something, somewhere

Comment: you are following correct way by using jsonEncode, i recommend watching a youtube video for the same for better understanding.

Comment: Instead of passing data to chart like data: jsonEncode(widget.chartData) ?? defaultData, you should first jsonEncode the list and prepare that before it gets passed to the Chart and you can do this maybe in the initState method or when any screen opens so don't directly pass this data to chart like this.